Do I need end caps when using downtube barrel adjusters?
I have a frame with downtube bosses (Velo Orange Polyvalent). Currently, I'm using flat handlebars with MTB shifters that already come with barrel adjusters. However, since my frame has downtube bosses instead of cable stops, I purchased downtube barrel adjusters.
I'm uncertain about how the shifting cable should be fitted in the barrel adjuster. Should I use an end cap? If so, I'm not sure which type to choose from my Jagwire Shifting cable set (sealed end cap, hooded end cap, line end cap).



I would use a ferrule (end cap, as you call it, also refers to the little piece that gets crimped on to the end of inner cable after excess length is trimmed off. "Cable end cap" is how it's refered to in technical & marketing documentation).
The type of ferrule is probably not too important other than it be for the typical 4mm diameter of the outer shift cable.  My personal preference would be one that is sealed at a minimum. Shimano technical documents would have you fit a ferrule with a tongue and rubber seal over that in that position if it were a cable stop (see photo below).  All that with a barrel adjuster might be too much in terms of a clean look and may interfere with the action of the barrel adjuster. The tongue portion of that type of ferrule may not easily fit through the end of the adjuster.
Again, I would use a sealed shift cable ferrule there.

